# Append value to JSON url, when checking a checkbox and automatically refresh JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, checkbox, reload

I would really need some help on this one.

```
<div id="entrylist"></div>

var urlSource = "http://www.example.com/catgories=Cat1,Cat,2,Cat3";
        $.getJSON(urlSource, function(data){
          $.each(data, function(i,entry){
           if(entry.LiveStatus == 3) { 
            content = '<div class="row filmate">';
            content += '<div class="large-4 columns no-padding">';
            content += '<a href="#" onclick="playVideo(&#39;' + entry.VideoStreamUrl + '&#39;)"><img src="' + entry.ThumnailUrl + '" /></a><p>' + entry.Viewers + '<img src="img/eyes.png" /></p>';
            content += '</div>';
            content += '<div class="large-8 columns no-padding">';
            content += '<h2>' + entry.Title + '</h2>';
            content += '</div>';
            content += '</div>';
        } else if(entry.LiveStatus == 2) { 
            content = '<div class="row filmate">';
            content += '<div class="large-12 columns no-padding">';
            content += '<h2>' + entry.Title + '</h2>';
            content += '</div>';
            content += '<div class="large-12 columns no-padding">';
            content += '<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal"><img id="ls-3" src="' + entry.ThumnailUrl + '" /></a><p>' + entry.Viewers + '<img src="img/eyes.png" /></p>';
            content += '</div>';
            content += '</div>';
        } else if(entry.LiveStatus == 1) { 
            content = '<div class="row filmate">';
            content += '<div class="large-12 columns no-padding">';
            content += '<h2>' + entry.Title + '</h2>';
            content += '</div>';
            content += '<div class="large-12 columns no-padding">';
            content += 'in direct<img src="' + entry.ThumnailUrl + '" /><p>' + entry.Viewers + '<img src="img/eyes.png" /></p>';
            content += '</div>';
            content += '</div>';
        } else {
            content = '<div class="row planificat">';
            content += '<div class="large-12 columns planned no-padding">';
            content += '<h2>' + entry.Title + '</h2>';
            content += '<p>planificat</p>';
            content += '</div>';
            content += '</div>';        
        };

            $(content).appendTo("#entrylist");




          });
        });
```

This is my JSON get & post code. Please give me a hint on how to:

1. Append a category to urlSource variable, when a checkbox is checked.
2. When that checkbox is checked, reload the JSON and show the new options

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use .val() from jquery - this will get the value from the form and then append it to the url.

http://api.jquery.com/val/

I would suggest for something like this that looking at the jquery documentation is good first  port of call as it can give you ideas on how to tackle problems like this.